# How to get return value True and false while check table name exist in DB or not ? (phonegap)

Tags: cordova

Hi can you please tell me how to check table name exist in data base or in phone gap .
I google it find this .

```
function populateDB(tx) {
            // drop the DEMO table if it exists
            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');  
            // create DEMO table with columns id and data
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
            // insert test data into DEMO table
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
        }
```

But I don't know how to check table exist or not.?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO` this should fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I done that my own ...using to This.

tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "'+CASENAME+'"(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, DocumentName TEXT NOT NULL,DocumentDate INTEGER ,DocumentNotes TEXT NOT NULL)');